# WPF datagrid and row data bound event?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF grid with autogeneratedcolumn set to true. I have to modify the template of a given cell for every row in the grid. Is there are an event in WPF datagrid which can allow me to capture every row and perform the necessary modifications before getting it rendered?

If not, then can you please suggest what could be the best way of customizing row cell's in an autogenerated datagrid?

Comment: Is the modification column-specific? Or can the cell modification in one column change for each row?

Comment: Modification is column specific. Suppose if a column matches a given criteria, then I have to change the template of every row in the grid for that particular column.

Comment: In that case, attach to the DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn event. You can replace the default column in DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.Column to a new one. For example, you could replace it with a new DataGridTemplateColumn with a custom CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate.

Comment: Or use a `DataTemplateSelector` instead of messing with events and do it the WPF way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a `DataTemplateSelector` instead of messing with events.  This will allow you to cleanly vary the cell template based on data in the cell programatically.  Hooking events in WPF inevitably leads to references getting held far long than you expect which manifests as memory leaks.

MSDN documentation is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Code From MSDN:

```
Namespace SDKSample
    Public Class TaskListDataTemplateSelector
        Inherits DataTemplateSelector
        Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(ByVal item As Object, ByVal container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate

            Dim element As FrameworkElement
            element = TryCast(container, FrameworkElement)

            If element IsNot Nothing AndAlso item IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf item Is Task Then

                Dim taskitem As Task = TryCast(item, Task)

                If taskitem.Priority = 1 Then
                    Return TryCast(element.FindResource("importantTaskTemplate"), DataTemplate)
                Else
                    Return TryCast(element.FindResource("myTaskTemplate"), DataTemplate)
                End If
            End If

            Return Nothing
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```